# Grouping WHERE clauses in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to produce the following SQL code using Active Records in Codeigniter:

```
WHERE name != 'Joe' AND (age < 69 OR id > 50)
```

Doing the following seems to be as far as I can get, I cant figure out how to group them

```
$this->db->select()->from('users')->where('name !=', 'Joe')->where('age <', 69)->or_where('id <', $id);
```

Any ideas? My SQL query is too complex so I dont wish to rewrite everything in traditional SQL.

**UPDATE**

My SQL code is dynamically generated depending on the values of certain parameters passed into the model method. The problem with not being able to use parenthesis causes a problem because the operator precedence is such that `AND` is evaluated first before `OR`.

*Here is a chunk of my active records code, where there are some other code before and after it:

```
            ... some $this->db->where() ...
            ... some $this->db->where() ...

    if($price_range) {
        $price_array = explode('.', $price_range);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($price_array); $i++) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $this->db->where('places.price_range', $price_array[$i]);
            } else {
                $this->db->or_where('places.price_range', $price_array[$i]);
            }
        }

    }

            ... some $this->db->where() ...
            ... some $this->db->where() ...
```

The problem comes because I am using `$this->db->or_where()` which introduces a `OR` clause that throws the operator precedence into disarray without being able to use `( )` to change the order.

** Is there any way to solve this? **

Comment: it doesnt' seem to be too complex to don't let your write it in plain SQL

Comment: @yes123: the example above is just an example, my active records alone generate up to 60+ lines of dynamically generated actual SQL code of which many are conditional SQL statements.

Comment: This is an unfortunate limitation of the Activerecord class in Codeigniter.

Comment: @timw4mail: any suggestion what I should do? Any alternatives to rewriting all in plain SQL?

Comment: @Nyxynyx the best way is probably to do the where clause as a plain sql string. The $this->db->where() method can take a plain string.

Comment: @timew4mail: looks like I have to construct the plain SQL code with parenthesis using PHP, then drop it into `$this->db->where()`, guess that may work

Comment: Just tried that out and it works great! :)

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Solved. Dynamically generate the SQL query and plug it into `$this->db->where()`. Thanks guys!

Comment: baaad, you loose string validation

Answer (score 32):

In Codeigniter 3 you can use:

```
$this->db->select()
  ->from('users')
  ->where('name !=', 'Joe')
  ->group_start() // Open bracket
    ->where('age <', 69)
    ->or_where('id <', $id)
  ->group_end(); // Close bracket
```

In Codeigniter 4 you can use:

```
$builder->select('*')
  ->from('users')
  ->where('name !=', 'Joe')
  ->groupStart()
    ->where('age <', 69)
    ->orWhere('id <', $id)
  ->groupEnd();
```

Perhaps it can help

Answer (score 15):

You can use one large string.

`$this->db->select()->from('users')->where("name != 'Joe' AND (age < 69 OR id > 50)
");`

Comment: I have updated the original question with some actual code from my project... As you can see I cannot use parenthesis `( )` like you do in your answer

Comment: @Nyxynyx So in the end your solution was to create one large string?

Comment: Yup, I created a partial plain SQL query string for the problematic part that requires parenthesis) and inserted it into `$this-db->where()`

Answer (score 13):

The grouping of where clauses is not in CI by default. You have to extend the core and add in the ability. I have done so by doing something as follows:

```
class MY_DB_mysql_driver extends CI_DB_mysql_driver 
{       
    public function __construct($params) 
    {
    parent::__construct($params);
    }
    /** 
     * This function will allow you to do complex group where clauses in to c and (a AND b) or ( d and e)
     * This function is needed as else the where clause will append an automatic AND in front of each where Thus if you wanted to do something
     * like a AND ((b AND c) OR (d AND e)) you won't be able to as the where would insert it as a AND (AND (b...)) which is incorrect. 
     * Usage: start_group_where(key,value)->where(key,value)->close_group_where() or complex queries like
     *        open_bracket()->start_group_where(key,value)->where(key,value)->close_group_where()
     *        ->start_group_where(key,value,'','OR')->close_group_where()->close_bracket() would produce AND ((a AND b) OR (d))
     * @param $key mixed the table columns prefix.columnname
     * @param $value mixed the value of the key
     * @param $escape string any escape as per CI
     * @param $type the TYPE of query. By default it is set to 'AND' 
     * @return db object.  
     */
    function start_group_where($key,$value=NULL,$escape,$type="AND")
    {
        $this->open_bracket($type); 
        return parent::_where($key, $value,'',$escape); 
    }

    /**
     * Strictly used to have a consistent close function as the start_group_where. This essentially callse the close_bracket() function. 
     */
    function close_group_where()
    {
        return $this->close_bracket();  
    }

    /**
     * Allows to place a simple ( in a query and prepend it with the $type if needed. 
     * @param $type string add a ( to a query and prepend it with type. Default is $type. 
     * @param $return db object. 
     */
    function open_bracket($type="AND")
    {
        $this->ar_where[] = $type . " (";
        return $this;  
    }   

    /**
     * Allows to place a simple ) to a query. 
     */
    function close_bracket()
    {
        $this->ar_where[] = ")"; 
        return $this;       
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
group_where_start(key,value)->where(key,value)->group_where_close()
```

or

complex queries like

```
open_bracket()->start_group_where(key,value)->where(key,value)->close_group_where()->start_group_where(key,value,'','OR')->close_group_where()->close_bracket() would produce AND ((a AND b) OR (d))
```

Comment: Excelent !!! I customize my driver. Did you suggest it to CI ? Can I put this into activeRec ?

Comment: Great! It really helped me out!
One might want to read this to get it working:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

Comment: Hey all, sorry been a while. No I haven't suggested it to CI. Just came out of necessity for me. Feel free to put it into activeRec @NicolasThery. Please set this as the correct answer so I can start posting more solutions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 9):

CI3 has all you need!

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', 'a')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')
->get();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 7):

What I've done is duplicate the and clause after the where, which is effectively the same as the long string selection.

```
$this->db->select()
  ->from('users')
  ->where('name !=', 'Joe')
  ->where('age <', 69)
  ->or_where('id <', $id)
  ->where('name !=', 'Joe');
```

The one large string way is probably better.

Comment: After trying in vain to get the parentheses right as described in @Jrod's solution, I took this approach which worked for me! Thanks.