# CodeIgniter $this->db->where(); Group Combine ANDs and ORs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create this select:

```
SELECT * FROM units
WHERE ((um like '%str%'  AND desc like '%str%') AND deleted = 0)
```

so i tried using

```
$search = 'str';

$this->db->from('units');
$this->db->where("(um LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%' or
desc LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%') and deleted=0");
return $this->db->get();
```

but that did not work, even though on my other tables, controllers, modules it works fine.
edit: I saw why it did not work, because of desc... but still my question goes below...

I tried using this and works properly

```
$this->db->from('units');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->like('desc', $search);
$this->db->or_like('um', $search);
```

But this formulates as:

```
WHERE deleted = 0 AND desc like  '%str%' AND um like  '%str%'
```

Can I combine or_like and like as 1? and where deleted as another, because now it shows all the deleted because of the or_like.

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter

Comment: was answered by creating dynamic where.

Comment: By the way - don't use `desc` as a column name - it's a keyword in some DBs - ie. MySQL

Comment: yeah found that the hard way. anyway I did not change it and used `desc` instead.

Comment: @Sid use units.desc instead of desc

Answer (score 0):

for this

> SELECT * FROM units WHERE ((um like '%str%'  AND desc like '%str%')
>   AND deleted = 0)

you have to do:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('units');
$this->db->where("((units.um LIKE '%str%'  AND units.desc LIKE '%str%') AND deleted = '0')",NULL);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: actually that wont work because you must do `desc` instead of desc. But I am looking to combine  like, or_like as a group ( )... May I know if it is not possible? thanks

Comment: @Sid can't catch you.. what you mean by **you have to do desc**? group() and like() are different commands , please write down the query you need to do and i can help you!

Comment: @Sid anyway you should be able to use **units.desc** instead of **desc**

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('units');
$this->db->where("(um LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%' or
desc LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%') and deleted=0");
return $this->db->get();