# codeigniter extend database driver call to undefined method my_db_mysql_driver::select()

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I need a custom active record class that can group where clauses. Upon stumbling i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter) and a tutorial on how to [extend the mysql driver](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers). Upon doing so, I receive an error of `Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_DB_mysql_driver::select()`. I have followed the steps stated on the tutorial but still no luck.

Here's my sql statement:

```
$this->db->select('post_id, post_title');
$this->db->from('articles');
$this->db->where($sqlParams);
$this->db->open_bracket();
$this->db->or_like($sqlLikeParams);
$this->db->close_bracket();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom active record class must `extends`  `CI_Model`

```
class Active_record extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }


  function your_function() { 

   /* Your code here*/
    $this->db->select('post_id, post_title');
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->where($sqlParams);
    $this->db->open_bracket();
    $this->db->or_like($sqlLikeParams);
    $this->db->close_bracket();
  }
}
```