# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::start_group_where()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am debugging a codeignitor project in which I am getting following error

```
Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::start_group_where()
```

I have looked into `CI_DB_mysqli_driver` Class but no such function is available there. I don't know what this function do.
It is getting called in one of my codeignitor function as following.

```
$this->_db->start_group_where($privacy_field, 1, '', $operator);
```

If anyone is aware of it please help.
Thank You.

Comment: Ithink its from there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter

Comment: which CI version in use?

Comment: Can you update your question with full Query(code)?

Comment: @splash58 yes i followed that post and looks like it solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping